# Edit the Outer Variable With the Class Constructor

Tags: constructor, dart, flutter

how do i edit the chattile variable in the contructor 'tambah' as shown below:

```
class ChatCardList extends StatefulWidget {
  List<ChatTile> chattile; //EDIT THIS
  ChatCardList({Key key, this.chattile}) : super(key: key);
  Future<void> _onSocketInfo_newMessage(dynamic data) async {
    ChatCardList _data = new ChatCardList.tambah(data);
  }

  ChatCardList.tambah(String message) {
    print("PESAN BARU : " + message);
   this.chattile.add(message); //PUSH OBJECT
  }
  print(chattile); //notting added
  @override
  _ChatCardListState createState() => new _ChatCardListState(chattile:chattile);
}
```

why did that happen? is my script wrong, or is there something missing from my code?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you go back and check that this is the actual code that is causing your problem.
The code displayed here will not compile at all, so it's hard to say where the real problem is. Alternatively, describe in detail what you are actually trying to achieve.

The `ChatCardList.tambah(String message) {` constructor does not initialize `chattile`, so the value of `this.chattile` in the body should be `null`. Calling `add` on that will throw. Otherwise that code is perfectly fine, it is how you add to a list stored in `this`'s `chattile` variable.

The `Future<void> _onSocketInfo_newMessage(dynamic data) async {` method creates a new `ChatCardList` using `CharCardList.tambah`, but never does anything with it (it doesn't return the value), so nobody will ever see that object or its `chattile` value.

Also, the `print(chattile);` code is outside of any function or constructor body, so it is really declaring an abstract method called `print` which takes a parameter named `chattile`. Since your class isn't abstract, that should cause a compile-time error.

So, one way to rewrite your program could be:

```
class ChatCardList extends StatefulWidget {
  List<ChatTile> chattile; //EDIT THIS
  ChatCardList({Key key, this.chattile}) : super(key: key);
  Future<void> _onSocketInfo_newMessage(dynamic data) {
    String message = data;
    this.chattile.add(message);
  }

  @override
  _ChatCardListState createState() => new _ChatCardListState(chattile: chattile);
}
```

This code doesn't introduce the `tambah` constructor, but instead updates the `chattile` list immediately in the `_onSocketInfo_newMessage` method. That method still needs to be called from somewhere.

Comment: so how is the best way to overcome this problem?

Comment: I have to ask "which problem?" because it isn't clear what you are trying to do, so it is impossible to say what you should do to get there. I'll add a potential fix, but I can't say whether it does what you want.